# String data type variable initialization

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

How to initialize a string data type variable by null character('\0')???

```
string txt='\0';
```

is it right or wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to embed a null character in the string? `string txt;` will already have a null terminator embedded in it and is like `const char* blank = "";`

Comment: C++ strings don't need terminating characters. C strings do.

Remember that in C and C++ single-quotes are used to create *individual characters* and not strings. C++ strings come ready to work with, no preparation required, unlike C.

Comment: default constructor will do that.

Comment: What's wrong with `string txt;`?

Comment: You can find the complete set of `string` constructors [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong, because there is no constructor of `std::string` which takes `char`. If you want to construct an `std::string` which has a null-terminator in it (for whatever reasons you might have) you should use different constructor:

```
std::string txt(1, '\0');
```

Please note, this is the answer which takes question on it's face value. You probably do not need this at all, but I do not know that for sure.

Comment: Note that the underlying char array then has two null terminators. `\0\0`

Answer (score 0):

First of all understand that to make `std::string::c_str()` work, `std::string` always allocates space for terminating zero, so most probably default constructor will do the job for you.

On other hand if you need string which length is not zero and contains zero inside there are two approaches.

1. use `std::string txt(1, '\0');` as @SergeyA sucgested in other ansewear. (this will work with old C++03)
2. use [string literal suffix operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), which is more handy IMO.

.

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
auto s2 = "\0"s;
```

[Here is live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HIFXthKii6YFgnSD).